# Bootstrap 3, navbar-toggler-icon Not Loading, Always Visible

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

When using the following navbar code, I'm having two issues: 
1. The actual navbar-toggler-icon isn't loading, I'm only seeing a small white square. 2. The icon is always visible, even when the navbar menu is full-width. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! I've been banging my head against a wall!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header-menu" aria-controls="header-menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kaitlyn Dornbier</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header-menu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7, as I've run into a lot of navbar trouble with Bootstrap 4

==================================================================
SOLUTION:
Sometime between Bootstrap 3.3.7 and the new beta Bootstrap 4, they renamed 'navbar-toggle' to 'navbar-toggler'! The navbar-toggler-icon is also new, and was replaed with three icon-bars, like the example shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggle-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header-menu">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kaitlyn Dornbier</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header-menu">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Ah, the three icon-bar spans helped! As for the constantly visible button, I ended up finding help by scrapping it and going back to the bare bones using w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp, turns out instead of 'navbar-toggler' it should have been 'navbar-toggle' - not sure why they would have changed it but that did the trick!

Comment: I see now that you also had the navbar-toggle in your code, hard variable name change to catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/capozzic1/pen/pWpvvN?editors=1000) of what I did. It's possible a jquery file was missing because bootstrap's collapse navbar depends on it to animate. I couldn't get navbar-toggle-icon to work, but I could get the bars using this:

```
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

I included this link to the jquery library so bootstrap could depend on it:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
```

In total, here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header-menu">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kaitlyn Dornbier</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header-menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```