# Fixing Bootstrap nav bar toggler

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble understanding what is going wrong with my Bootstrap navbar toggler on my application.  I've reduced it to a simple example.  Note that Bootstrap version is 3.4.1 with JQuery 1.12.4.

The toggler works, per se, but it appears as a squished pancake on a line above the actual navbar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Why does the navbar toggler not work properly?</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-controls="myNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="myNavbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <h1>Some Stuff</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/Lrqxn652/

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I finally tracked down the problem, and there is actually another post it it here at Stack Overflow.  The answer is provided here:

[Bootstrap 3, navbar-toggler-icon Not Loading, Always Visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577875/bootstrap-3-navbar-toggler-icon-not-loading-always-visible?rq=1)

In short, there was a change somewhere in the 3.x range of Bootstrap where navbar-toggler was changed to navbar-toggle, and the navbar toggler icon doesn't use a span as shown anymore, but rather three spans with class icon-bar.